# How to use Interface Example.PropertySelector

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use `PropertySelector` in `Example` in hibernate but I didn't find any example on net that guide how to use it.

I found document here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.PropertySelector.html

Basically what I am trying to do is

```
Example example = Example.create(user); 
PropertySelector propertySelector;
propertySelector.include(user, "emailId", org.hibernate.type.Type);
```

It gives error `org.hibernate.type.Type cannot be resolved to a variable`, so what to use in third argument?

Comment: You need to create your own `Type`, unless there are already pre-made ones. Judging from the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/type/Type.html) you should probably create a new instance of one of the known implementing classes.